# name 'sc' is not defined,

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, data-science

2 days back I could run pyspark basic actions.
now **spark context is not available** sc.
I tried multiple blogs but nothing worked.
currently I have python 3.6.6, java 1.8.0_231, and apache spark( with hadoop) spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7

I am trying to run simple command on Jupyter notebook

```
data = sc.textfile('airline.csv')
==> getting following error.
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-572751a2bc2a> in <module>
----> 1 data = sc.textfile('airline.csv')

NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

i have set following system variable set

```
HADOOP_HOME = C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7 
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON = ipython
PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS = notebook
SPARK_HOME = C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7
(java and python system variables are already set)
path = C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7\bin ( i have loaded winutils.exe in this folder)
```

Now if I remove my `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS` variables and run pyspark on my command prompt, then i get following error.

```
C:\spark-3.0.0-preview-bin-hadoop2.7>pyspark
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
19/12/25 23:28:36 WARN NativeCodeLoader: **Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable**
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
19/12/25 23:28:42 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
19/12/25 23:28:42 WARN Utils: Service 'sparkDriver' could not bind on a random free port. You may check whether configuring an appropriate binding address.
19/12/25 23:28:42
```

I tried to find workaround for this too but couldn't get it. Please help

Comment: are you sure you have above sc = spark.sparkContext??

Comment: add from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext("local[*]", "spark_context")

Answer (score 0):

i dont know why but this is how it works
i am using my company's laptop.
when i connect to company's network using Pulse secure, my spark context connects successfully. and when i connect to my home network then it doesn't.

strange but that's how it is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

@GiovaniSalazar is right. You need to import

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row, SparkSession
```

and define sc

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
sc = spark.sparkContext
```

then refer to sc

```
data = sc.textfile('airline.csv')
```

in your case.